# Retrieve Data from Database Showing Records per User - Laravel

Tags: php, mysql, laravel, bootstrap-4

I am trying to understand how to retrieve a record from the database which was submitted by a specific user and display that one single record. Currently, I am retrieving all submitted posts with a simple forelse loop. The idea is to display this information in Bootstraps card title view (photo below). Ultimately, as the user posts more content the view layout would look something like this https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.0/examples/album/

As the user adds more posts I would like to retrieve them all but display each post in a single Card title as below. Can anyone help me understand this process to get this ultimately working?

[image]

@foresle loop

```
@forelse($posts as $post)
    <p><strong>
            <a href="/posts/{{ $post->id }}">{{ $post->title }}</a>
            </strong></p>
@empty
    <p>No Posts Currently</p>
@endforelse
```

Comment: You can copy the html from the [bootstrap 4 docs](https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.0/components/card/) inside your forelse, and replace the content of card-title by `{{ $post->title }}` and the same for the <img> src, <a> href and so...

Comment: what's your opinion about using `foreach()` instead?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can achieve this type of view using the following code:

```
<div class="row">
    @forelse($posts as $post)
    <div class="col-md-4">
        <div class="card mb-4 box-shadow">
            <img class="card-img-top"
                 src="{{ $post->image }}"
                 data-holder-rendered="true">
            <div class="card-body">
                <p class="card-text">{{ $post->title }}</p>
                <div class="d-flex justify-content-between align-items-center">
                    <div class="btn-group">
                        <a href="/posts/{{ $post->id }}" class="btn btn-sm btn-outline-secondary">View</a>
                    </div>
                    <small class="text-muted">9 mins</small>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
    @empty
        <p>No Posts Currently</p>
    @endforelse
</div>
```

Comment: You're very much welcome - there are many more fun things to do with Laravel. Have fun and keep coding 

Comment: Hi Chris, quick question, for ``` <small class="text-muted">9 mins</small>``` whats the best way to show this for actual time of submission? any suggestions?